# Musical notes are not aligned correctly

Tags: musixtex

I am following a course on music and want to make my notes with LaTeX and MusixTeX. I have 2 staves for 1 instrument and the notes are not alligned vertically. When I put all notes on 1 `\note` line the result is worse. All notes are printed at 1 position.

*What do I do wrong or is this normal?*

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{2}
\startpiece
  \notes \zh{ceg} | \zh{j} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj} | \zh{j} \en
  \notes \zh{gik} | \zh{k} \en
  \notes \zh{ceg} | \zh{l} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj} | \zh{m} \en
  \notes \zh{gik} | \zh{n} \en
  \notes \zh{ceg} | \zh{n} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj} | \zh{o} \en
  \notes \zh{gik} | \zh{p} \en
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the spaces around the `|`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{2}
\startpiece
  \notes \zh{ceg}|\zh{j} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj}|\zh{j} \en
  \notes \zh{gik}|\zh{k} \en
  \notes \zh{ceg}|\zh{l} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj}|\zh{m} \en
  \notes \zh{gik}|\zh{n} \en
  \notes \zh{ceg}|\zh{n} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj}|\zh{o} \en
  \notes \zh{gik}|\zh{p} \en
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]